# Books in mathematics based on problem solving

Tags: problem-solving, puzzle, applications

Hi I'm looking for mathematical books that try to teach mathematical concepts by motivating and solving real life problems. For example a book in topology that is motivated by problems of  planetary surface. Or group theory by motivating it from crystal structures. Probability and statistics motivated from making exit poll predictions.

NOTE: I'm looking for math books that actually teach how to use the theory to approach a problem-- something beyond regular applied math books. Books such as 
Probability Theory by Jaynes

Comment: I don't see any meaningful distinction in your "note" paragraph... Not that there isn't any distinction, I just mean the difference is not large enough to warrant telling posters they can't post some books for that reason.

Comment: Uhm, yes. What about that Note?

Comment: Sorry if the note is confusing but I'm looking for books that talks about strategies to approach a problem not essentially the solution that is common in most applied math books. Something I believe on the lines of How to solve it by Poyla

Comment: I'm a fan of [Linear Algebra, Geodesy, and GPS](http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Geodesy-Gilbert-Strang/dp/0961408863) by Gilbert Strang.

Comment: Thank you littleo thats precisely kind of books I was asking for

Comment: Real-life problems are really complicated. If you want to introduce new and advanced mathematical concepts to an audience, it is probably best to stick to the simplest examples possible, the more trivial the better to start with. That usually leaves out real-life problems.

Answer (score 0):

One go-to book for that sort of thing is *[For all practical purposes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1429254823)*.

It's aimed more at a general audience, though, so the depth of math is limited. It gives a good sampler of diverse applications. I don't know if it has any discussion of topology, but it does cover a lot of discrete math things that are very accessible.